# Change page title in confluence without changing URL

Tags: url-rewriting, confluence, page-title

The page URL in confluence is generated using the page title.
Is there a way to change the title of an already  established page without changing its original URL?
I tried using the link from the share button, that link directs me to the page regardless of the title.
But the original link has already been shared many times over, so retroactively we can't use the share link.
I've also tried using a new title and landing on a redirect page. But it makes for a poor user experience